# Angular 2.0.0-beta.2 router injecting unwanted '?' suffix into route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm forcing a route change using this code (corresponding with a button click). The full method looks like this:

```
submit(){
  this.store.dispatch({type: MasterScreenerActions.SUBMIT});
  this.router.navigateByUrl('master-screener-results');
}
```

Now, this works just fine, but if I hit back on the browser and then click the `submit` button again, the browser will navigate to like so: `Navigated to http://localhost:4200/master-screener-results?`. Notice the `?` at the end. However, after the browser will eventually arrive at the proper url, ie `/master-screener-results`, after reloading the application etc. The problem is that this route is only intended to be activated or connected after filling out various forms, the hinted at `master-screener`.

Why is this behavior and how is it occurring? Should `master-screener-results` be a child component? Do I need to implement some type of guard? Any advice or tips on where to begin looking is very much appreciated.

edit: I also end up getting a `?null=on` suffix on my route after some fiddling... what does this mean?

edit2: this behavior seems to occur if and only if the template has been loaded previously, ie, `zone.js:101 XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:4200/app/master-screener-results/master-screener-results.component.html".`, the next call will result in `Navigated to http://localhost:4200/master-screener-results?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the very same problem with you just now. What I had was something like this:

```
<form>
  <input ...>
  <button (click)="submitForm()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and the code:

```
submitForm() {
  // do something
  this.router.navigate(["../home"], {relativeTo: this.r});
}
```

After debugging I realised that it only happens when I click a `<button>` inside a `<form>`, but not on clicking an `<a>`; which leads to my conclusion that the `button`'s default action is not prevented. And this change helps me:

```
submitForm() {
  // do something
  this.router.navigate(["../home"], {relativeTo: this.r});
  return false; // prevent default action
}
```